# iText - PDFAppearence issue

Tags: pdf, itext, signature

We're using iText to put a text inside a signature placeholder in a PDF. We use a code snippet similar to this to define the Signature Appearence

```
PdfStamper stp = PdfStamper.createSignature(inputReader, os, '\0', tempFile2, true);
sap = stp.getSignatureAppearance();
sap.setVisibleSignature(placeholder);           
sap.setRenderingMode(PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.DESCRIPTION);
sap.setCertificationLevel(PdfSignatureAppearance.NOT_CERTIFIED);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
sap.setSignDate(cal);
sap.setLayer2Text(text+"\n"+cal.getTime().toString());
sap.setReason(text+"\n"+cal.getTime().toString());      `
```

Everything works fine, but the signature text does not fill all the signature placeholder area as expected by us, but the area filled seems to have an height that is approximately the 70% of the available space.

As a result, sometimes especially if the length of the signature text is quite big, the signature text does not fit in the placeholder and the text is striped away.

Example of filled Signature:

[image: Example of filled Signature]

I looked into the PdfSignatureAppearence class and I found this code snippet in the getApperance() method that is responsible of this behaviour and is invoked when

```
sap.setRenderingMode(PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.DESCRIPTION);
```

is being called

```
      else {
            dataRect = new Rectangle(
                    MARGIN,
                    MARGIN,
                    rect.getWidth() - MARGIN,
                    rect.getHeight() * (1 - TOP_SECTION) - MARGIN);
      }
```

I don't get the reason for that, because I expect that the text could use all the available placeholder height, with the proper margin.

Is there any way to bypass this behaviour?

We are using iText 5.4.2, but also newer version contains same code snippet so I expect that the behaviour will be same.

Comment: You can always construct the appearance completely yourself.

Comment: Could you provide me an example of a fully configured appearence? I made some test, but the problem is that by setting the Layer2Text attribute the code snippet I posted is being executed and as a result there's always a margin at the top. I believe that by putting only text in the signature, this space could be avoided, but as TOP_SECTION attribute of the PDFSignatureAppearence.java is final and can't be modified it's somehow impossible to customize it as we would like to.

Comment: I think this is a bug. TOP_SECTION is connected with acro6layers rendering and the code does not take into account the value of the acro6layer flag.

Comment: @FrancescoTimperiTiberi *"Could you provide me an example of a fully configured appearence"* - confer my answer: It shows how to configure a custom layer 2 for the signature appearance. If need be, you can configure the other layers similarly. But there usually is no need to touch them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JJ. already commented,

> TOP_SECTION is connected with `acro6layers` rendering and the code [determining the `datarect` in pure `DESCRIPTION` mode] does not take into account the value of the `acro6layer` flag.

Unless one wants to fix this in the iText 5 code itself, the easiest way to make one's description use the whole signature space is to construct the layer 2 appearance oneself.

To do so one merely has to retrieve a `PdfTemplate` from `PdfSignatureAppearance.getLayer(2)` and fill it as desired after one has called `PdfSignatureAppearance.setVisibleSignature`. The `PdfSignatureAppearance` remembers that you already have retrieved the layer 2 and doesn't change it anymore.

For the case at hand we essentially copy the `PdfSignatureAppearance.getAppearance` code for generating layer 2 in pure DESCRIPTION mode, merely correcting the code determining the `datarect`:

```
PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = ...;
[...]
appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(36, 748, 144, 780), 1, "sig");

PdfTemplate layer2 = appearance.getLayer(2);
String text = "We're using iText to put a text inside a signature placeholder in a PDF. "
        + "We use a code snippet similar to this to define the Signature Appearence.\n"
        + "Everything works fine, but the signature text does not fill all the signature "
        + "placeholder area as expected by us, but the area filled seems to have an height "
        + "that is approximately the 70% of the available space.\n"
        + "As a result, sometimes especially if the length of the signature text is quite "
        + "big, the signature text does not fit in the placeholder and the text is striped "
        + "away.";
Font font = new Font();
float size = font.getSize();
final float MARGIN = 2;
Rectangle dataRect = new Rectangle(
        MARGIN,
        MARGIN,
        appearance.getRect().getWidth() - MARGIN,
        appearance.getRect().getHeight() - MARGIN);
if (size <= 0) {
    Rectangle sr = new Rectangle(dataRect.getWidth(), dataRect.getHeight());
    size = ColumnText.fitText(font, text, sr, 12, appearance.getRunDirection());
}
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(layer2);
ct.setRunDirection(appearance.getRunDirection());
ct.setSimpleColumn(new Phrase(text, font), dataRect.getLeft(), dataRect.getBottom(), dataRect.getRight(), dataRect.getTop(), size, Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
ct.go();
```

*([CreateSignature.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/signature/CreateSignature.java#L430) test `signWithCustomLayer2`)*

(As description text I used some paragraphs from the question body.)

The result:

[image: Screenshot]

By adapting the `MARGIN` value in the code above, one can even use more are. As that can result in the text touching the border, though, that might not be really beautiful.

---

As an aside:

> if the length of the signature text is quite big, the signature text does not fit in the placeholder and the text is striped away.

If you initialize the `size` variable above with a non-positive value, the code in the `if (size <= 0)` block will calculate a font size which allows all of the text to fit into the signature rectangle. This does happen in the code above as `new Font()` returns a font with a size of `UNDEFINED` which is a constant `-1`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, we're going to implement this suggestion in our signing code.