# Delete padding of Rectangle in iText PDF signature

Tags: java, pdf, itext, sign

I have a little app to add a signature to a PDF in JAVA using iText.
This is a fragment of the code:

```
PdfReader           reader  = new PdfReader(pdfBytes);
FileOutputStream    fos     = new FileOutputStream(new File("/home/john/signedPdf.pdf"));
PdfStamper          stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(
                            reader, 
                            fos, 
                            '\0', 
                            new File("/home/john/"), 
                            true
    );
PdfSignatureAppearance signatureAppearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
signatureAppearance.setRenderingMode(PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.DESCRIPTION);
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(
                36,
                748 - 20 * (next - 1) ,
                144,
                780 - 20 * (next - 1)
    );
rectangle.normalize();
signatureAppearance.setVisibleSignature(
        rectangle, 
        1, contact);
```

The PDF is signed good, but the visible sign in the rectangle has a padding and one rectangle get over the second, and second get over third, etc.
This is the example image:
[image]
[image]
Exist a way to delete this padding and evit one rectangle get over other.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Which `RenderingMode` do you use? In case of `RenderingMode.DESCRIPTION` the padding on all four sides is identical at 2pt but considering the frame lines in your screen shots that does not appear to be the case for you. That been said, whether or not rectangles overlap depends on how you choose rectangle coordinates. Unfortunately you don't show your relevant code for that either, the `setVisibleSignature` call...

Comment: @mkl I update the code. I add RenderingMode.DESCRIPTION and ectangles overlap persist.

Comment: The signatures have been created for neighbouring values of `next`? Like for 1 and 2?

Comment: I don't understand well your question ( my english is not very good ). next is an Integer to control the order of the sign. If no have signatures next is 0, and the rectangle write out in this position, if have a 1 sign ( exist a rectangle ) i write the next rectangle right down and so on.

Comment: You use a variable `next` in your code. Have the two overlapping signatures being created by your code with consecutive values for next? E.g. has the topmost signature been created for `next == 1` and the lower one for `next == 2`?

Comment: exactly, i update my previous comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169109/discussion-between-jose-javier-hernandez-benitez-and-mkl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use rectangles created like this for your signatures

```java
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(
                36,
                748 - 20 * (next - 1) ,
                144,
                780 - 20 * (next - 1)
    );
```

where (as clarified in comments) the integer `next` can have consecutive values for the signatures, e.g. 1 and 2.

But this means that you actually ask for overlapping signature rectangles! E.g. for for the values 1 and 2 you get:

- `next == 1` - rectangle top **y**: 780; rectangle bottom **y**: 748
- `next == 2` - rectangle top **y**: 760; rectangle bottom **y**: 728

So these rectangles overlap for **y** between 760 and 748.

If you don't want your rectangle to overlap, the **y** step factor (currently 20) must be at least as large as the difference between the top and bottom **y** coordinate start values (currently 780 - 748 = 32).

E.g. you can use a step factor of 32

```java
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(
                36,
                748 - 32 * (next - 1) ,
                144,
                780 - 32 * (next - 1)
    );
```

or a rectangle height of 20

```java
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(
                36,
                760 - 20 * (next - 1) ,
                144,
                780 - 20 * (next - 1)
    );
```

instead of your current rectangle dimensions and locations.

Comment: Thanks! That works. but there is a fill between the text and the upper edge of the rectangle. Is it possible to eliminate it?

Comment: @JoseJavierHernándezBenítez I'll have a look when I'm in office tomorrow.

Comment: Ah, the reason is that the top 30% of the rectangle explicitly are left empty, and when I looked at the code, I remembered that I wrote an answer on that issue before, cf. [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45859595/1729265).